# Should I expect þingvellir to be snowcovered early May?

Tags: weather-and-climate, iceland

I will have a 72 hour layover on Iceland 1–4 May, and I will happen to have my bicycle with me.  I am considering to go on a cycling trip to þingvellir and some other places.  However, I'm unsure about weather conditions.  Should I expect þingvellir to be covered in snow at the beginning of May?  I don't mind if the hills/mountains are snowcovered, but I'll be cycling with my summer tyres so if snowfall or snow-blocked roads are likely, it might be wiser for me to make different plans.

Comment: Flickr can do searches by date - this can sometimes give you a pretty good idea of what to expect. Here's a search for images of [þingvellir from 1st of May to 15th of May 2014](https://www.flickr.com/search/?q=%C3%BEingvellir&d=taken-20140501-20140515&ct=0&mt=all&adv=1).

Comment: I've lived several years and Iceland and while it can be expected to have snowy days in May or even June, the snow isn't really able to *cover* anything anymore by that time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say no, not on the roads or paths, but there is only one thing you can expect from Iceland's weather - that it's unpredictable. Last year I've been to þingvellir in late February and there was no snow on roads or paths, unless you drove through the mountains. However, this year the winter they have is so fierce, they consider [giving it a name](http://grapevine.is/news/2015/03/12/icelanders-consider-naming-winter/)!

I recommend these websites when planning trips:

[Road conditions (with camera images)](http://www.vegagerdin.is/english)

[Weather forecast](http://en.vedur.is/)

Have fun! Iceland is a truly beautiful place.

Comment: Ok!  Then I just hope the wind is not so fierce that I can't make it to Þingvellir (or other nearby places) and back from Keflavík in 72 hours :)

Comment: _I_ got from Reykjavik to Þingvellir in a day, and another 15 miles after. Believe me, if I can do it, you can. (It's true, I needed a pep talk from my wife every few miles once the hills started.) Be prepared for headwinds. You might even think of goggles, if you don't wear eyeglasses.

Also note that there are few snack opportunities on the road once you are east of Mosfellbaer, and that there is a semi-marked bike path to get out of Reykjavik. You don't want to get trapped on the expressway.

Comment: Finally my 3-day cycling trip did not happen because Icelandair decided to deliver my bicycle 24 hours after myself... but I still did a beautiful 1-day cycling trip Selfoss–Geysir–Selfoss.  Þingvellir will have to wait to another trip.  Weather was sunny but chilly (5°C) and windy (35 km/h).